# How to identify the rainfall “non-events” from a time -series data under R?

Tags: r, dplyr, statistics, zoo

My goal is to identify the rainfall “non-events” from the time-series data. the rainfall “non-events” is defined when “the sum of rainfall (rainfall accumulation) during 6 hours is less than 1.27mm”.

I inspired my script with loreabad6's solution provided to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51371155/r-select-rainfall-events-and-calculate-rainfall-event-total-from-time-series-da) (my goal is not exactly the same):

Firstly, I used the moving sum for each 36 rows (36 * 10 min interval) (see section 2.1 in ("rollsum" column) in the script below)

Then, I wanted to repeat the number "1" for 36 times for each first "1" found in the rows of the "rainflag " column (calculated in section 2.2) and if I find another number "1" after line 36 (when there are several rainfall “non-events” which succeeds), I will begin to put the number 1 for 36 times also and so on….(step 2.3). The rest of the rows take the value "0".

```
                       **Edit**
```

I want to calculate at the end the column "no_event", illustrated in the attachment. In this example I presented the duration of 36 hours only by 3 values.

[image]

Can you help me please in step 2.3, what is the logic to use in order to identify the rainfall "no events"!

Thank you in advance

My script :

```
#  data example
library (RainfallErosivityFactor)
data (RainFallExample, package="RainfallErosivityFactor")
data=RainFallExample
head(data)

library(dplyr);library(zoo)

#1# Concatenate date and hour : 
data0=mutate(data, datetime= as.POSIXct(paste(date,Hora), format = '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M'))
head(data0)

#2# Estimate the "non avent" rainfall = rainfall Sum during 6 hours < 1.27mm

flags <- data0 %>% 
    #2.1# rollsum each 36 (6 hours = 36 * (10 min))
  mutate(rollsum=rollapplyr(rainfall, 36, sum, fill = NA, align = "left")) %>%

  #2.2# Set a rain flag : if the rollsum >1.27 we give the value 0 otherwise 1
  mutate(rainflag = ifelse(rollsum > 1.27, 0, 1)) %>% 

  #2.3. 
    mutate(no_event = ifelse(rainflag==1, rollapplyr(rainflag, 36, sum, fill = NA, align = "right"), 0)) 

 head(flags)
View(flags)
```

Comment: Just to clarify, your step 2.1 gets the cumulative rainfall in the 6 hours following that timestep (if the row is 6h00, this is calculating rainfall between 6h00 and 12h00) and then step 2.2 signifies if there is a rainfall non-event in the following 6 hours. However, your step 2.3 is interested in the past 6 hours? This is all signified by the align argument

Comment: Sorry I am not able to follow what you want to do for 2.3. When should `no.eve.length` be 1 and when should it be 0?

Comment: Thank you m.evans and Ronak Shah for your reply. Now I have given an example (see edit in a question above). So I wanted to calculate at the end the "no_event" column. Thank you again!

Comment: Are there any other proposals please. Thank you