# R: Isolating values from a Time Series based on calculations done within the Time Series?

Tags: r, dataframe, time-series

I have a time series that can sometimes be irregular in interval. Simplified example:

```
Timestamp, Rain
04:00    , 0
05:00    , 0
06:00    , 0
07:00    , 0
08:00    , 0
09:00    , 0
10:00    , 0.2
10:10    , 0.2
10:20    , 0.3
10:30    , 0.2
10:40    , 0.1
10:50    , 0
11:00    , 0
12:00    , 0.1
13:00    , 0
14:00    , 0.1
15:00    , 0
16:00    , 0
17:00    , 0
18:00    , 0
19:00    , 0
20:00    , 0
21:00    , 0.1
22:00    , 0.1
23:00    , 0
```

I need to create a secondary table sourced from the original table that would look like this:

```
Timestamp_rain_Start, Timestamp_rain_End
10:00   , 14:00
21:00   , 22:00
```

The criteria for the start row is that it is a "point of rain where there is no rain for 6 hours prior" and the end row being a "point of rain where there is no rain for 6 hours after".

I understand that basic math can be carried out on POSIXct formats, so I'm imagining the code would contain something where for i in x$timestamp, the sum between x[i-6hr,1] and x[i,1]. Sum between x[i,1] and x[i+6hr, 1] for end column. I've looked at using a for loop to isolate the rows, but can't seem to figure it out.

Any help would be much appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Hi @cobacapy! could this be relevant? https://stackoverflow.com/a/59031230/13818750

Answer (score 2):

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- tribble(
  ~Timestamp, ~Rain,
     "04:00",     0,
     "05:00",     0,
     "06:00",     0,
     "07:00",     0,
     "08:00",     0,
     "09:00",     0,
     "10:00",   0.2,
     "10:10",   0.2,
     "10:20",   0.3,
     "10:30",   0.2,
     "10:40",   0.1,
     "10:50",     0,
     "11:00",     0,
     "12:00",   0.1,
     "13:00",     0,
     "14:00",   0.1,
     "15:00",     0,
     "16:00",     0,
     "17:00",     0,
     "18:00",     0,
     "19:00",     0,
     "20:00",     0,
     "21:00",   0.1,
     "22:00",   0.1,
     "23:00",     0
  ) %>%
  mutate(Timestamp = hms::parse_hm(Timestamp))

df$last_six_hours <- df$next_six_hours <- NA

for(i in seq(NROW(df))) {
  df$last_six_hours[i] <- df %>%
    filter(
      df$Timestamp[i] - df$Timestamp <= 6*60*60,
      df$Timestamp[i] > df$Timestamp
    ) %>%
    pull(Rain) %>%
    sum()
  df$next_six_hours[i] <- df %>%
    filter(
      df$Timestamp - df$Timestamp[i] <= 6*60*60,
      df$Timestamp[i] < df$Timestamp
    ) %>%
    pull(Rain) %>%
    sum()
  }
tibble(
  Timestamp_rain_Start = filter(df, last_six_hours == 0 & Rain > 0) %>% pull(Timestamp),
  Timestamp_rain_End = filter(df, next_six_hours == 0 & Rain > 0) %>% pull(Timestamp)
)
#> # A tibble: 2 × 2
#>   Timestamp_rain_Start Timestamp_rain_End
#>   <time>               <time>            
#> 1 10:00                14:00             
#> 2 21:00                22:00
```

<sup>Created on 2022-03-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thanks! Will be dissecting this in the next few days.